# If a variable with internal linkage is referenced in a block, do I need to use the extern keyword in that block?

Tags: c, variables, scope, linkage

I am trying to nail down all of the nuances of variable declarations in the context of scope and linkage.

Consider the following two snippets of code:

---

**Code 1** Block *without* `extern` declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int i=4;

int main()
{
  {
    i++;
    printf("i is %d \n",i);
    i++;
  }
  printf("i is %d \n", i);
  i++;
  printf("i is %d \n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
i is 5
i is 6
i is 7
```

---

**Code 2** Block *with* `extern` declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int i=4;

int main()
{
  {
    extern int i;
    i++;
    printf("i is %d \n",i);
    i++;
  }
  printf("i is %d \n", i);
  i++;
  printf("i is %d \n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
i is 5
i is 6
i is 7
```

---

Given that these two code snippets **generate the same output**, I am going to assume that they are functioning in an identical manner "under the hood" (i.e. the compiler generates the same resulting executable).

So here is the question:

Is **Code 2** simply a "polite", user friendly way of carrying out Code 1 (i.e. you are informing the reader, "Hey...this variable `i` has been defined elsewhere within this file"?). So does `extern`'s use in this manner simply satisfy some sort of convention?

Comment: Code 2 is making an unnecessary (re)declaration of `i`.  Many programmers will regard it as unhelpful.  In general, you should not declare `extern` variables inside a function.  There's a GCC warning `-Wnested-externs` option to warn about nested `extern` declarations — that is, `extern` declarations inside functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ahhh. That's great to know. The only reason I asked is because in my book C Programming: A Modern Approach, the author SEVERAL TIMES uses code 2-esque examples when talking about variable declarations (Pg 463 and 465, for example)

Comment: Mr King's book?  That's a pretty good book.  In theory, you should know about what `extern` inside a function means, but that still leaves it as debatable practice.  I take the view that all such declarations — functions or variables — are undesirable, even though the language allows them.  GCC has options to support my prejudices, though they are not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the `extern` declaration adds nothing.  The same variable named `i` is referenced with or without that declaration.

An example of where an `extern` declaration at block scope matters is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i=4;

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  {
    extern int i;
    i++;
    printf("i is %d \n",i);
    i++;
  }
  printf("i is %d \n", i);
  i++;
  printf("i is %d \n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

In this case a variable named `i` with block scope and no linkage masks the variable of the same name with file scope and external linkage.  Then at the inner scope, the `extern` declaration makes `i` refer to the variable at file scope.

This code then outputs:

```
i is 5 
i is 0 
i is 1
```

Also note that in this case the `i` at file scope cannot be `static`.  This is because the `extern` declaration looks at the innermost variable with the given name to determine the linkage of the identifier.  If the prior declaration has no linkage then the `extern` declaration refers to a variable with external linkage.  This will conflict with a file scope variable declared `static`.

This is detailed in section 6.2.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`
> in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,
> if the prior declaration specifies internal or external  linkage,  the
> linkage  of  the  identifier  at  the  later  declaration  is  the
> same  as  the linkage specified at the prior declaration.  If no prior
> declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no
> linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

Comment: Of course, code like that is an abomination in its own right (for all that it is valid C code). 
 GCC has the `-Wshadow`  option to report places where a local variable hides a more nearly global variable.  It would have fits with your example code.

Comment: @dbush Thank you for the provided example. However, I am having a little bit of trouble understanding your last paragraph (when you explain why the variable i that is declared as an external linkage, if, instead, was declared as an internal linkage...with everything else kept the same...would be invalid)